Why does the connection remain open even when removed from DOM?
I'm using .NET 8 Blazor Server and I have a component with the following code block:
@if (isStreaming)
{
    <img src="@streamUrl" />
}

When a button is pressed the isStreaming property is toggled. The img src is a mjepg url that remains open and is streamed to the browser. The button's @onclick event is bound to the method:
private void CloseStream()
{
    streamUrl = String.Empty;
    StateHasChanged();
}

Here is where I am confused, when it is set up as such and the button is pressed the connection closes and no longer shows in the browser. However, if I add isStreaming = false to the line before StateHasChanged(); The <img> tag doesn't appear in the DOM yet the connection remains open. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the connection terminate? The <img> tag is no longer on the page and even before that happened the URL was set to an empty string.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    streamUrl = "https://examplestream"; //mjpeg
}

Called by Parent Component with:
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<StreamComponent stream="@clickedstream" @key="@clickedstream"></StreamComponent>


There are multiple reasons that the connection could remain open before your StateHasChanged() method executes.  You have not shown how you manage the stream on the server side, nor what your StateHasChanged() method does.  Blazor updates to the client side do not also manage the underlying server side stream.  I suspect your StateHasChanged() method has some explicit management of the stream.

@Kevin StateHasChanged() is a Blazor method from ComponentBase to re render the component. It is not mine.

Can you produce a [MRE] to demonstrate the problem?

if you didn't override StateHasChanged() that also will not explicitly close the underlying stream.  The underlying stream is managed independent of the DOM elements in Blazor.  You're missing a piece of code here that does explicitly manage the stream.  As long as the connection to the host for the stream remains open, the stream continues.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I've added a little bit more which I think is everything that is being used.

This is a bit of an educated guess.  I think that when you use isStreaming to add/remove the img element, the render object is removed from the RenderTree, but still active and streaming [the src isn't reset].  It therefore can't be disposed.  When you leave the element in place with the src set to string.empty, it's streaming is reset.

PS - using  @rendermode InteractiveServer and @attribute [StreamRendering] is contradictory.  It's an or, in your case @attribute [StreamRendering] is ignored.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis That was I was thinking as well initially but couldn't be sure as I'm new to blazor, what should I do then if I want the img tag removed from the render tree and reset the src? There's no real reason for this off the top of my head but I just don't want a blank img tag sitting in the page. Also thanks for the info about the rendermode and attribute, I did not know that.

I've moved away from doing the conditional rendering in a lot of places - such as showing or hiding buttons.  I now use the hidden attribute.  Try <img src="~/favicon.png" hidden="@!isStreaming" />'. 
